# Как передать звук с ПК на сайт?

Tags: javascript, php, delphi

В общем есть прога на Delphi, записывает 3 секунды с микрофона и отправляет на сайт через post, на сайте php скрипт записывает звук в бд, и оттуда собственно его достаёт и присваивает в audio element src, звук передаётся, все работает, но не так как бы хотелось.. Есть вот эта небольшая задержка между записями, хотелось бы реализовать это как потоковую запись, где без прерываний воспроизводится звук. Есть идеи как это сделать?)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: О какой задержке речь? Во время отправки записи, обработке, получении или во время записи? Зачем используется прога на Delphi, можно ли обойтись без неё? Конкретизируйте..

Comment: Нужен аудиопоток с микрофона? Используйте [ffmpeg](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1466/live-audio-stream-using-ffmpeg). Хотите сделать что-то свое? Смотрите в сторону потоковых протоколов, POST - это не поток, задержка будет по определению.

Comment: объяснять саму суть. нужно записать звук с микрофона программой на Delphi, а на сайте я должен эту запись получить и воспроизвести, причём сделать это всё как трансляцию звука, что-то типа радио вещания. задержка в моём случая получается когда загружается следующая запись, то есть между передачей одной записи в 3 секунды и второй возникает задержка.(данные с клиента передаются постоянно, записал -> отправил -> записал -> отправил)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно предположить, речь о задержке между записями и что запись и отправка идет в одном потоке и пока отправляет, программа не пишет звук. Разделите на 2 потока, лучше 3. В одном пишите звук в кеш, во втором выбирайте и пишите в кеш готовые отрывки 3 сек, в третьем уже делайте отправку на сайт.
Это в случае если если отправка на сайт именно в таком формате принцимпиальна.

Comment: Порядок,не принципиален, спасибо за совет) Но меня вот волнует как не просто подставлять в тег <audio> src, а как бы дописывать чтоб аудио файл играл без остановки(паузы)

Comment: сделал чуть иначе, записываю 2 буфера просто. Во время первой записи начинаю вторую, а во второй снова вызывает первую. А на самом сайте ставлю проигрывание просто с 1 секунды xD. Ну и получается задержки как таковой нет, костыли конечно, но что делать...